# BigQuery Python Client with Job Config To Write Results Yields Permission Denied Error

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-iam

I am having problems writing my query results to a table in BigQuery.

```
table_id = "projectid.mydataset.mytable"

job_config = QueryJobConfig(destination=table_id)
#some data wrangling here
sql = """
    
    select * from `bigquery-public-data.geo_census_tracts.census_tracts_alabama` 

"""

# Start the query, passing in the extra configuration.
query_job = bq_client.query(sql, job_config=job_config)  # Make an API request.
query_job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete.

print("Query results loaded to the table {}".format(table_id))
```

I keep getting the follwogin error

> Forbidden: 403 Access Denied: Table
> bigquery-public-data:geo_census_tracts.census_tracts_alabama: User
> does not have permission to query table
> bigquery-public-data:geo_census_tracts.census_tracts_alabama.
>
> ```
>                        -----Query Job SQL Follows-----                           
>
> |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    1:    2:    select * from
> ```
>
> `bigquery-public-data.geo_census_tracts.census_tracts_alabama`    3:
> |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |    .    |

But when I query and extract it as a dataframe, no problem.

[image]

I do not know what I am missing, I already gave the service account enough access.

[image]

Comment: Can you let me know if you are able to successfully execute this [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries#bigquery_simple_app_query-python)? If yes, please include these [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#required_permissions) to the service account created during the quickstart and try running your code.

Comment: Were you able to execute the quickstart successfully and add required permissions to the service account? Does it resolve the permission issue?